# Opencart 2.x - empty Dashboard no Stats etc

Tags: opencart

I have migrated openc art from 1.5.4 to 2.3.0.2
All works but the dashbaord is not shown . Not  a blank screen but header menu is there no content no Statistics etc.
i checked .tpl  and php in common/dashboard . it seems correct.

could it be permsision related or database 
have some one a idea
Greetngs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a clearer instruction on how to fix the no stats in dashboard issue:

Go to  C-Panel/phpMyAdmin then select your database:

1. Backup your database by exporting it.
2. Click on SQL and paste the code below:

INSERT INTO `oc_extension` (`type`, `code`) VALUES
('dashboard', 'activity'),
('dashboard', 'sale'),
('dashboard', 'recent'),
('dashboard', 'order'),
('dashboard', 'online'),
('dashboard', 'map'),
('dashboard', 'customer'),
('dashboard', 'chart');

INSERT INTO `oc_setting` (`store_id`, `code`, `key`, `value`, `serialized`) VALUES
(0, 'dashboard_activity', 'dashboard_activity_status', '1', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_activity', 'dashboard_activity_sort_order', '7', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_sale', 'dashboard_sale_status', '1', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_sale', 'dashboard_sale_width', '3', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_chart', 'dashboard_chart_status', '1', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_chart', 'dashboard_chart_width', '6', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_customer', 'dashboard_customer_status', '1', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_customer', 'dashboard_customer_width', '3', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_map', 'dashboard_map_status', '1', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_map', 'dashboard_map_width', '6', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_online', 'dashboard_online_status', '1', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_online', 'dashboard_online_width', '3', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_order', 'dashboard_order_sort_order', '1', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_order', 'dashboard_order_status', '1', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_order', 'dashboard_order_width', '3', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_sale', 'dashboard_sale_sort_order', '2', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_customer', 'dashboard_customer_sort_order', '3', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_online', 'dashboard_online_sort_order', '4', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_map', 'dashboard_map_sort_order', '5', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_chart', 'dashboard_chart_sort_order', '6', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_recent', 'dashboard_recent_status', '1', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_recent', 'dashboard_recent_sort_order', '8', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_activity', 'dashboard_activity_width', '4', 0),
(0, 'dashboard_recent', 'dashboard_recent_width', '8', 0);

Reference SQL file: https://github.com/pekka2/OpenCart-Migration-Upgrade-Tool/blob/master/SQL/dashboard.sql

Thanks to pm-netti

Answer (score 0):

I found out that i could  not install the extensions for dashboard like activity , order, chart etc in admin /backend.

So i manually activated installed them in database.

oc_extension 
extension_id  type          code
28            dashboard     chart

Answer (score 0):

[Use this fix](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=28561)

Is a problem in the dashboard extension file: don't concatenate a prefix to the module name on *install* and *uninstall* (just like other extensions)

Open: *admin/controller/extension/extension/dashboard.php*

find this line:

```
$this->model_extension_extension->install('dashboard', 'dashboard_' . $this->request->get['extension']);
```

Should be on line 19 if file isn't edited, (install function). Replace it with:

```
$this->model_extension_extension->install('dashboard', $this->request->get['extension']);
```

In other words, remove *"'dashboard_' . "*

Do the same with line 41 (uninstall function)

```
$this->model_extension_extension->uninstall('dashboard', 'dashboard_' . $this->request->get['extension']);
```

Replace with:

```
 $this->model_extension_extension->uninstall('dashboard', $this->request->get['extension']);
```

It works fine to me. I don't know if the prefix "dashborad_" is used somewhere, however seems pretty useless since the column "type" in the DB entry is setted to "dashboard"...so is easy to recognize that is a dashboard extension.

Another strange behaviour with dashboard: if module's width sum isn't a multiple of 12, dashboard won't show the last one. Erro is in file: *admin\controller\common\dashboard.php*. To fix it, after the last foreach closing brace (line 78) add:

```
 if (!empty($column)){
      $data['rows'][] = $column;
 }
```

I have uploaded the fix on the Opencart market place [here](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=28561)